# Using results list scroll as a trigger in Autocomplete.js

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, triggers, autocomplete

I am fairly new to Javascript and enjoying using  [Autocomplete.js](https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/). However, I am having difficulty understanding how to use the 'trigger' config based upon the documentation.

As I understand it, by default any input into the autocomplete box will trigger the function within src (). I am attempting to configure this function to be triggered when a user scrolls to the bottom of the results list (in order to gather more results).

If anyone has any template code or suggestions on how to setup autocomplete.js to gather/append items to the results list when a user scrolls to the bottom that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks again!